# How to we login to docker hub(private registry) using chef recipe?

Tags: docker, chef-infra, chef-recipe, docker-registry

I'm using docker_registry with user name and password in the recipe but I'm unable to get connected successfully.

Code:

```
docker_registry 'https://hub.docker.com/' do
  username 'XXXXXX'
  password 'XXXXXX'
end
```

Comment: Trying this way to see whether this works:- 
docker_registry 'https://cloud.docker.com/login/' do
 username 'XXXXX' 
 password 'XXXXX' 
end

Comment: This didn't work either... :-|

Answer (score 1):

URL for official docker registry is `https://index.docker.io/v1/`. It is even [mentioned in cookbook documentation](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker#docker_registry).